# ngResource search google news, but return results: Array[0]

Tags: angularjs

sample code as follow,Is it about hl?locale? Many thanks.

```
.factory('newsResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E');
}])

newsResource.get(
  function(successResponse){
    console.log(successResponse);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `JSONP` when making a request to an external domain and it seems the googleapis also support the `JSONP`.

You could change your `$resource` to use `JSONP` instead like this:

```
.factory('newsResource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E', {}, {
    get: {
      method: 'JSONP',
      params: { callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK' }
    }
  });
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jCDqCErP9UKLWuhBOtp4?p=preview